# URL draft specification validate method

Tags: javascript, parsing, url

I've been looking at the new [URL specification](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/) which is now implemented in Chrome Canary, and it looks very useful.

Is there any way to validate a URI before it is passed into the `URL` object?

**For example**

```
var urlToCheck = "http//www.google.com";
if(URL.isValid(urlToCheck)) {
    var u = new URL(urlToCheck, baseUrl);
    console.log(u.hostname);
}
```

I can't see anything in the linked specification doc. I would really not like to have to process the thrown Exception just to check the URI is valid.

Comment: "I would really not like to have to process the thrown Exception just to check the URI is valid." --- wrap it in your function

Comment: Unfortunately both the url and the base URL throw a TypeError exception, so I wouldn't know which URL is invalid. `new URL("http://www.google.com", "asd123")`, the URL is indeed valid, but the base is not. I'd rather test each URI separately.

Comment: In the 2 parameter URL constructor, the base is the only thing that can be invalid. See also my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the 2-parameter version of the URL constructor accepts anything as its first parameter:

```
try{
    new URL(null, 'http://www.example.com');
    new URL({ob:'jects',even:{nested:'ones'}}, 'http://www.example.com');
    new URL(['arrays'], 'http://www.example.com');
    new URL(/regexes/, 'http://www.example.com');
    new URL(false, 'http://www.example.com');
    new URL(undefined, 'http://www.example.com');

    console.log('new URL() takes any value as its first parameter!');
}catch(e){}
```

This means you don't have to validate both URLs; you only have to validate the base URL. Therefore a simple solution like this should suffice:

```
URL.isValid = function(url) {
    try{
        new URL(url);
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You said in your comment that you can't tell if it's the base URL or the URL that's invalid so you'd rather check them both separately. If so, why not just do that? For example, something like this:

```
URL.isValid = function(url, base) {
  if(base !== undefined) {
    try {
      new URL(base);
    }
    catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  try {
    new URL(url, base);
    return true;
  }
  catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Lets you check both at the same time if preferred, or as you said you wanted, separately by first checking URL.isValid(base) and then checking URL.isValid(url, base). If the first check fails you know base is invalid, if the second does, you know url is invalid. If you really wanted, you could return separate error codes from .isValid based on which url was invalid.

Comment: +1 This is almost exactly what I was going to post! :) Since there's no way to access the URL parser aside from the constructor itself—at least, according to the interfaces described in the spec—this seems like the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to validate url:

```
function isValidUrl(url) {
    return url.match(/^(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/);
}
```

Comment: here's a nice cheat sheet: http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html

Comment: I really don't want to rely on Regex. The functionality is in there *somewhere*, I want to know where and if we can use it.